# Finding all the characters of $\mathbb C^\times$

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, characters

I am trying to determine all the characters on the group $\mathbb C^\times$ of non-zero complex numbers under multiplication. I believe that all the characters are given by:
$$\chi : z=re^{ix} \to {r\over r}e^{ikx}=e^{ikx} \quad for \ k \in \mathbb R$$
But I'm not sure if this is correct or if this is all of the characters for $\mathbb C^\times$.

Note: The definition of character I am using is: A character of a locally compact abelian group A is a continuous group homomorphism:
$$\chi :A \to \mathbb T$$
where $\mathbb T$ is the circle group i.e. the multiplicative group of all complex numbers of absolute value 1.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089968/character-and-representations-of-bbb-c-times?rq=1) seems related.

Comment: I believe that the definition of a character used in the answer to that question is different to the definition of a character that I was given so they are possibly two different things. I have added the definition I was given for clarity

Comment: The definition in the link is almost the same as yours. Your map is simply compose $\mathbb{C}^\times\to\mathbb{C}^\times\to\mathbb{T}$, where the first map is the character in the linked question and the second map is the contraction onto $\mathbb{T}$.