# Irreducible representations of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, complex-numbers, representation-theory, lie-groups

Suppose you have a smooth irreducible representation (finite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$) of $G = \mathbb{C}^{*}$, then does it have to be of the form $z.w = z^n w$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $w \in \mathbb{C}$?

note that the representation has dimension $1$ since $G$ is abelian. Note the result folds for $G=S^1$. I would be grateful for a reference.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089968/character-and-representations-of-bbb-c-times?rq=1

Comment: The answer there assume that it is an algebraic irreducible representation, in which case the result is true. I was already aware of this. Also if the corresponding homomorphism is algebraic then it is true by the identity theorem, by using the classification of irreps of $S^{1}$.

Comment: The rep $z.w=|z|^2 w$ is smooth in the sense of real manifolds, but isn't holomorphic, so there should probably be a holomorphic restriction if you want to exclude these.

Comment: Thanks!, that was exactly what I wanted.