# Algebraic representations of multiplicative group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $\mathbb{G}_m = \mathrm{Spec}(k[t, t^{-1}])$ be the multiplicative group ($\mathbb{G}_m(R) = R^\times$). I know there is a equivalence between representations of $\mathbb{G}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}-$gradations: actually, $\mathbb{G}_m$ is a diagonalizable (see [here](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AGS.pdf), page 219), $k[t, t^{-1}] = k[\mathbb{Z}]$ the group algebra of the integers and there are an equivalence
$$
\mathbb{G}_m-\text{representations}
\iff
k[t,t^{-1}]-\text{comodules}
\iff
\mathbb{Z}-\text{gradations}
$$
More precisely, 1. all representations are semisimple , 2. the irreps are one-dimensional (both are true for all diagonalizable group) and 3. given by $\rho^n_R(r) = r^n \in R^\times$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

On the other hand, I can look the group $k^\times$ and define a representation $\rho: k^\times \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ of this group to be algebraic if for all $v \in V$ and $f \in V^*$ we have $\rho_{f,v} = f(\rho(-)\cdot v): k^\times \to k$ a rational function. I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089968/character-and-representations-of-bbb-c-times) that for $k = \mathbb{C}$: 1. all algebraic representations of $k^\times$ are semisimple (maybe i can do it using some Weyl unitary trick, maybe here $\mathbb{C}$ is important), 2. all irreps are one-dimensional and 3.given in the exactly same way. But now the classification of those 1-dimensional irreps are trivial, using just series equality.

The question: there are some connection between representations of an affine algebraic group $G$ and the group of $k-$point $G(k)$? I mean, I want those facts above to be the same in some sense. Sorry if that is a silly question.

Comment: Not all representations of affine algebraic groups are semisimple, for example the additive group or any other unipotent group (subgroup of strictly upper-triangular matrices) has many non-semisimple representations.

Comment: oh,  you are right. It's true only for diagonalizable groups.  I will edit.

Comment: Actually, a representation of the additive group is equivalent to given a locally nilpotent operator. So I guess the only finite dimensional irrep is the trivial one. But all irreps are finite dimensional, thus all semisimple modules would be trivial.